Convert PDF to JP2000 at 300 dpi and preserve the PDF page size
I have a PDF with a page size/dimension of 36 x 24 in. I would like to convert the PDF in JP2000 at 300 dpi, and keep the same size/dimension.
I use the code below but for some reason dpi are always set to 72 dpi. Do you know what I am doing wrong?
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
from PIL import Image
import tempfile
import os
import pypdf
from pypdf import PdfReader

def get_pdf_page_size(pdf_path):
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as f:
        reader = pypdf.PdfReader(f)
        page = reader.pages[0]           
        width = page.mediabox.width        
        height = page.mediabox.height
    return width, height

def pdf_to_jp2(pdf_path, output_folder, dpi=300):
    # Get PDF page size
    pdf_width, pdf_height = get_pdf_page_size(pdf_path)
    print(pdf_width, pdf_height)
    # Convert PDF to PIL images
    images = convert_from_path(pdf_path, dpi=dpi, size=(int(pdf_width), int(pdf_height)))
    
    # Create output folder if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)

    # Save each image as JP2 with the same dimensions as original PDF
    for i, image in enumerate(images):
        # Resize the image to match PDF dimensions
        #jp2_image = image.resize((int(pdf_width), int(pdf_height)), resample=Image.LANCZOS)       
        # Save as JP2
        jp2_path = os.path.join(output_folder, f'pz_{i+1}.jp2')
        #jp2_image.save(jp2_path, 'JPEG2000', dpi=(dpi, dpi))
        image.save(jp2_path, 'JPEG2000', dpi=(dpi, dpi))
    print("Conversion complete.")


# Example usage:
pdf_file_path = r'C:\gis\p2023\jp2\pdf\a1\A203.pdf'
output_folder = r'C:\gis\p2023\jp2\pdf\a1'
pdf_to_jp2(pdf_file_path, output_folder)

